# R data.table - aggregate partially within group and perform operation

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a nice way to make a sub-group within a grouping column in `data.table` operations?

The result I would like is the output from this:

```
dt <- data.table(
  group = c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c"),
  value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
)

dt[group!="a", group:="Other"][, sum(value), by=.(group)][]
```

which gives

```
group V1
a     6
Other 30
```

However, this alters the original `data.table`. I don't know if there is a different way to do this that wouldn't involve merging two `data.table`.  I can imagine a more complicated use case where I want `group %in% c("a","b")` as one sub-group and `group %in% c("c","d")` another, etc.

Comment: `dt[, sum(value), by = .(group = ifelse(group == "a", "a", "other"))]`?

Comment: Re the "more complicated use-case", just put the mapping into a separate table and do a join: `mDT = data.table(g = c(1,1,2,2), group=letters[1:4]); dt[, sum(value), by=mDT[dt, on=.(group), x.g]]`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is like a SQL right excluding join (using the terminology [here](http://asp-tech.blogspot.com/2010/08/joins-in-sql-server.html))

You can go through by group and within each group perform an anti-join

```
#group no longer found in .SD, hence make a copy of the column
dt[, g:=group]

#go through each group, anti-join with other groups, aggregate value
dt[, .(
        sumGrpVal=sum(value), 
        sumNonGrpVal=dt[!.SD, sum(value), on=c("group"="g")]
    ), by=.(group)]
```

or an even faster way:

```
dt[, .(
    sumGrpVal=sum(value), 
    sumNonGrpVal=dt[group!=.BY$group, sum(value)]
), by=.(group)]
```

output:

```
   group sumGrpVal sumNonGrpVal
1:     a         6           30
2:     b        15           21
3:     c        15           21
```